# How do pointers allow Hardware access?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Pointers in C are very powerful and seem efficient. But how can using a pointer can give you access to hardware?

My idea of this would be setting a pointer's value equal to a hardware's associated object and than manipulating it through the pointer. But if you already have enough access to the hardware's objects and properties to use a pointer on it where does the pointer come into play? Perhaps im visualizing something wrong?

I'm running on windows 7.

A basic example along with an explanation of why the pointer is needed to manipulate that hardware property would be great.

Comment: Yap. It gives you direct access to raw memory (with some constraints).

Comment: Depends on the hardware and OS. What are you using?

Comment: Are you asking about [memory mapped I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O)?

Comment: If you have an OS in the middle you should use drivers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pointer holds a memory address. And not all of the memory addressing range points to RAM areas alone. Memory addresses have ranges and some ranges map to hardware registers. And by writing to these registers, we can access the hardware. Of course, this also depends on which operating system and which hardware. Here is an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O#Example).

Comment: Thank you so much that did actually make a lot of sense to me...the example along with your explanation. My question came from a statement that said java doesn't have any direct hardware access, therfor it could not be used to program malware. For example:Java cannot keylog because it cannot read keystrokes outside of it's preconfigured client area. It also cannot read the keyboards' hardware. I was trying to ask how a pointer is needed to access that kind of hardware...I mean, why can't you just use the software based input to get which keys were pressed, as opposed to recording the hardware?

Comment: I am not asking how to hack or create malware just to clarify.

Comment: Compiled Java bytecode run on the Java virtual machine. When these bytecodes are executed by the virtual machine (VM), it runs the C/C++ code which the VM is made of (or that its libraries are made of) and this C/C++ code can use pointers to accesses the hardware. But normally this code access OS drivers, which use pointers to access the hardware. So, Java programs can't directly be malware, unless the underlying VM, library or drivers have security holes that allow the Java code to exploit it, and access the hardware in ways that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 7):

In a free standing environment (like a microcontroller), a hardware platform that does not
have a [Memory Management Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) (some ARM microprocessors), or an operating system that
does not support hardware protection (like DOS) pointers give you raw access to hardware
through the magic of [memory mapped I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). Pointers in program running on an operating
system like Windows or Linux (or just about any modern operating system) are pointers in
a [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). These pointers will not allow you to directly access
hardware.

The way that memory mapped I/O works is that certain physical memory addresses are
reserved for communication with devices in the system. When an address that belongs to a
device is accessed the data is routed to the appropriate register of the device. On x86
platforms this translation is done by the north bridge.

Answer (score 2):

Most hardware is memory mapped. What this means is that it exposes a range of hardware registers (or other hardware entities) as memory areas. These memory locations can be accessed like any other memory. You can read and write to it by using memory addresses - and these reads and writes make things happen in the hardware. Just as an example, a write to a hardware register (a memory address) may cause a LED to turn on, or a robot motor to start turning. All hardware operations are exposed via such memory mapped registers etc.

Now pointers are language entities that let you access a memory location. You stick an address into a pointer and dereference it to read (or write) from (or to) that address. So, basically the way you  operate the hardware is by accessing its address space via pointers.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense, thank you. Say for example I was writing to that particular register that turned on an LED. Would I need to know what kind of data to write to that register, and how would I find out what kind of information that hardware would need to perform certain functions?

Comment: If you are using a particular microprocessor or microcontroller, you can refer to the datasheet or reference manual for that processor. For e.g. for the Microchip PIC16F877 microcontroller, you can find the datasheet [here](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010241). It explains how to use the registers - what to write to them to get the intended effect.

Comment: Hardware comes with detailed specs for its programming interface. It explains in great detail what registers are available, what bit patterns to write to them, in what sequence, to invoke the supported behaviors. Note that, most hardware vendors provide reference software as libraries or drivers that can be either used directly, or as a reference for constructing your own software.

Comment: You just answered a huge question for me. I guess that's why in graphics libraries like Direct X a huge number of the functions and the typdefd variables are defined as hexadecimal numbers huh? Theyre actually accessing hardware huh?

Comment: Haven't seen the code. But on most OSes, the code is not going to use hard coded physical addresses. The hardware address space is mapped by the kernel at boot time (e.g. the PCI system), and then obtained by the driver. The physical addresses are mapped to virtual addresses before use (in kernel space or user space).